# How to verify and assert all the drop down values

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am getting the values from a drop down as calOptions.
The options printed in Output are as expected, but I am unable to assert the drop drown options with the list I have created: My_list = [All, Overdue]
I need to verify if the drop down options are "All" and "Overdue". Please help.

```
my_list = ["All", "Overdue"]
global calOption 
calOptions = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*/p-dropdownitem")
for calOption in calOptions:
      print(calOption.text)
Assert calOption.text == my_list

**Output:**
All
Overdue

assert <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="2a371065044a85d7da742d003742ce30", 
element="58647425-0660-4dd4-aad9-9a517f40730e")> == ['All', 'Overdue']
======================Assertion Error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to compare expected and actual drop-down values:

```
my_list = ["All", "Overdue"]
cal_options = [element.text for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*/p-dropdownitem")]
assert my_list == cal_options
```